# how to center this div in this page

Tags: css

This is the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/cJTNw/

html code is

```
<div id="container_m">
        <div id="div1" class="portlet-content">
            <div class="chartHeaderClass" style="width: 100%;">
                <h3 style="margin-left: 40%">Abandons</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="vertical-chart" class="chart-holder" style="border: 1px solid #D5D5D5; margin-top: 2px">
                <canvas class="overlay" width="478" height="265"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="div2" class="portlet-content">
            <div class="chartHeaderClass" style="width: 100%;">
                <h3 style="margin-left: 35%">Average Waiting Time</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="vertical-chart2" class="chart-holder" style="border: 1px solid #D5D5D5; margin-top: 2px">
                <canvas class="overlay" width="478" height="265"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="div3" class="portlet-content">
            <div class="chartHeaderClass" style="width: 100%;">
                <h3 style="margin-left: 35%"># In Queue</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="vertical-chart3" class="chart-holder" style="border: 1px solid #D5D5D5; margin-top: 2px">
                <canvas class="overlay" width="478" height="265"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="div4" class="portlet-content">
            <div class="chartHeaderClass" style="width: 100%;">
                <h3 style="margin-left: 35%">Service Level</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="line-chart" class="chart-holder" style="border: 1px solid #D5D5D5; margin-top: 2px">
                <canvas class="overlay" width="478" height="265"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The div id surrounding everything is container_m

My problem that I couldn't center that div. though I tried a lot like margion:auto and margion:0 and posision fixed with left 50 
but every time, even the div centered, the other elements inside it change its width.

Please help.

Comment: Well `margin: 0 auto` wouldn't work because the container has no set width. That means its taking up `100%` width. Also, why not use classes for your div's? They are all the same so there is no need to use `id`.

Comment: @Ruddy it is a possiblility to use class instead of id, but now the problem is I am not able to center it.

Comment: Check my answer for more information.

Comment: [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/cJTNw/7/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comment, using `margin: 0 auto` wouldn't work due to there being no defined width. This leaves the `div` to take up `100%` width.

Now for this I would set the width of the container and then set the `div`'s inside to `width: 100%;`.

I have removed the `id`'s that were being used as there was no reason for them and replaced them with `.divs`.

**CSS:**

```
.divs {
    width:100%;
    height:45%;
}

#container_m {
    width: 46%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/cJTNw/3/)

**Note:** There is not much point of having the `width: 100%;` as a `div` by default is a `block` element so it will be `width: 100%;` anyway. Its just there to show you whats going on.

---

You could also set them on the inside `div`'s as they have a width but then there is no real need for the container.

**CSS:**

```
.divs {
    width:46%;
    height:45%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/cJTNw/4/)

**Note:** I have removed the container as there is no need for it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
.portlet-content{
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And remove the margin-left: 2%; on all the id divs

Answer (score 0):

Provide all 4 div have a `class`. And put `margin: 0 auto`; for the class.

**Eg:**

```
.divclass
{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**OR**

provide `margin: 0 auto` for all 4 div `id`.